# Sqlite Full Text Search Query Puzzle

Tags: sqlite

I have data in format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.` It is stored as text.

I want a query that matches a given day(`yyyy-MM-dd`).

E.g

```
Select * from test where test MATCH '2014-03-30*'
```

When i try that, it returns all data excluding that of March 2014.

If i try

```
Select * from test where test MATCH '2014-04-30*'
```

It returns all data excluding that of April 2014.

I am puzzled!...i am getting the opposite of what i want!

Any reason for the strange behavior?

This is my full code....testing for date pattern

```
public List <Transactions> GetTransactionsVirtual(String token)
    {
List<Transactions> trans = new ArrayList<Transactions>();
SQLiteDatabase db;


String sql= " Select "  + MESSAGE + "," + TDATE +  ","+ SERVICE_PROVIDER +
            "  from " + TABLE_NAME_VIRTUAL + " Where "+ TABLE_NAME_VIRTUAL + " MATCH " +  "?" +
            " Order by " + TDATE + " DESC";
//check entered string...if date string strip it ..
String pattern="^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
String tokenedit=null;
String newtoken=null;
if (token.matches(pattern))
{
    tokenedit= token.replace("-", " ");
    Log.e("testtoken", tokenedit);
     newtoken =  tokenedit+"*" ;
}else
{
     newtoken= token+ "*";
}



String [] args= new String[]{newtoken};
Log.e("sqlamatch", sql);

db= this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, args);

   if(c.moveToFirst())
   {
       do{
           Transactions t=new Transactions();

           t.setTransactiondate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TDATE)));

           t.setMessage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MESSAGE)));   


           t.setServiceprovider(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SERVICE_PROVIDER)));

           //Log.e("msg",t.getMessage().toString());

           trans.add(t);
       }while(c.moveToNext());
   }
   return trans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full-text search mechanism is designed for searching words inside texts.

With the default [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer), the three fields of a date (`yyyy`, `MM`, `dd`) are parsed as single, independent words, and the delimiters are ignored.

An FTS query like `2014-03-30*` searches for documents (=records) that

- contain the word `2014`, and
- do not contain the word `03`, and
- do not contain any word beginning with `30`.

You need to do a [phrase search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test MATCH '"2014 03 30"'
```

If all you data has a fixed format, you should not use an FTS table in the first place.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion works (tried it in sqlite manager).  Problem is that i have two columns. One with regular texts . ..the other is that with date but stored as text and i am using a single search textbox to input the search words...it works for real words but i wanted to also include dates.

Comment: Searching for any other `-` will not work either. You have to convert the search input into a search query.

Comment: I have an idea...i am  planning to use regexpression to test entered string...if it matches the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd", use replace function to replace - with empty space...

Comment: seem to be working ...String sql= " Select "  + MESSAGE + "," + TDATE +  ","+ SERVICE_PROVIDER +
            "  from " + TABLE_NAME_VIRTUAL + " Where "+ TABLE_NAME_VIRTUAL + " MATCH " +  "?" +
      " Order by " + TDATE + " DESC";
String pattern="^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
String tokenedit=null;
String newtoken=null;
if (token.matches(pattern))
{
 tokenedit= token.replace("-", " ");
 Log.e("testtoken", tokenedit);
  newtoken =  tokenedit+"*" ;
}else
{
  newtoken= token+ "*";
}

String [] args= new String[]{newtoken};
Log.e("sqlamatch", sql);

Comment: But what happens when the user enters `hard-boiled`?

Comment: the Regex will catch that! not so?

Comment: That regex will not match "`hard-boiled`"; the database will search for record with `hard` and without `boiled`. Is it that what you want?

Comment: my searches willl be only for single words and dates...it is not for complex searches!...btw, how do i get character " in code? character code 32?